# How could i display view above actionbar without using dialogs?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I want to display a fadding view over content including actionbar. I can't use dialogs for that.

How could i display view above actionbar without using dialogs?

Comment: Use a customized toast, and animate it.

Comment: Maybe this link can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279647/display-view-on-top-of-action-bar

Answer (score 1):

If you mean on top of the action bar. You could try adding windowOverlay attribute to the action bar style. Then your layout will be placed from top of the screen instead of underneath the action bar.